# If $(T^*)^n$ converges pointwise in $\ell^1$, what can we conclude about $T^n$?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

Suppose $T$ is a bounded linear operator on all $\ell^p$ spaces including $\ell^\infty$. Suppose I know that for all $x \in \ell^1$, $\lim_{n \to \infty} \| (T^*)^n x \|_{\ell^1}=0$, but the convergence is not uniform. Here $T^*$ is the formal adjoint of $T$ (if $T$ has matrix representation $T_{ij}=t_{ij}$ then $T^*$ has matrix representation $(T^*)_{ij}=t_{ji}$). Can I conclude anything useful about $T^n$? In particular I would like to have $\lim_{n \to \infty} \| T^n x \|_{\ell^\infty}=0$ for all $x \in \ell^\infty$ but I suspect that that is too optimistic.

Comment: What is $ T^*$?

Comment: I am only familiar with the dual operator in Banach spaces being defined as a $T^*\in B(Y^*,X^*)$ for any $T\in B(X,Y)$, so how do we define $T^*x$ for $x\in \ell^1$? Are we assuming that $T$ is also an operator on some predual of $\ell^1$?

Comment: @K.Power You can think of everything in explicit matrix form: $(T x)_i=\sum_{j=1}^\infty T_{ij} x_j$ and $(T^*x)_i=\sum_{j=1}^\infty T_{ji} x_j$. (Thus this is the "formal adjoint".) If you like you can reverse the role of $T^*$ and $T$ so that we are given information about $T$ and want to learn something about $T^*$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The usual example with the right and left shifts apply. Let 
$$
Tx=(0,x_1,x_2,x_3,\ldots).
$$
Then $Te_j=e_{j+1}$, so $T_{kj}=\delta_{k,j+1}$. Then $(T^*)_{kj}=\delta_{k,j-1}$, and 
$$
T^*x=(x_2,x_3,\ldots).
$$
We have 
$$
\|(T^*)^nx\|_1=\sum_{k\geq n}|x_k|\to0,
$$
while
$$
\|T^nx\|_\infty=\|x\|_\infty.
$$
The same $T$ gives a counterexample for any pair $p,q$ (not necessarily conjugate): 
$$
\|(T^*)^nx\|_p\to0,\ \ \|T^nx\|_q=\|x\|_q.
$$

Comment: Hmm, it really seems like something should be possible in my particular case, but yes, this does rule out the general case. Thanks.

Comment: Glad I could help. I edited into the answer that the example also works for any pair $p,q$ of norms.

Comment: A twist that might work: what if I just want to ask that $(T^n x)_i \to 0$ for all fixed $x$ and $i$? Now the shift example obviously does not work (simply take $n \geq i$ and then $(T^n x)_i=0$ for all such $n$). But part of the difficulty is that this is to be requested for all $x \in \ell^\infty$, which is obviously a problem.

Comment: And of course that works, because $(T^n x)_i=e_i T^n x$ and $e_i T^n \to 0$, then if $x \in \ell^\infty$ then Holder's inequality does the job. So indeed the only "obstacle" is the same obstacle that prevents the result from holding for the shift operator.